# How do I design the retrieval and processing of all user roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, roles

I am building an intranet with ASP.NET core 2.0 MVC. All users are part of an active directory. Additionaly I have a MSSQL database with the following tables:

```
Users (Id, FirstName, UserNameAd (unique), ...)
Roles (Id, RoleName)
UserRoles (User_Id, Role_Id)
```

In my web application I now want to retrieve the roles of a user and store them in the Authentication/Identity Classes of Microsoft in order to use `[Authenticate(Roles="Admin")]` stuff. I am not sure where I shall put this role-request and what is the best practice. It is possible that a user gets a new role during the day or that a role is removed during the day and I actually do not want the user to click something specific or need him to restart the browser in order to get the new roles applied - thats why I think that the roles need to be requested with each server-action (POST, GET) from the server.

Any idea or link to a good tutorial would be highly appreciated.

Also if you think my approach is not good practice and you have a better idea I would be happy to know.

Comment: You should avoid hard-coding authorization and RBAC in your application. Leverage existing tooling e.g. read your roles from an LDAP rather than a homegrown database or use something like ABAC / XACML

Comment: This intranet will handle hundreds of users and ~ 80 different systems with different modules. That's the main reason why we do not want to have Active-Directory Groups, because we thinkt this will totally flood our AD. Can you please explain why you think we should not use RBAC in this application? I also do not understand what you mean by "hardcoding". Where is the difference from storing sth in the database or in an XACML?

Comment: See my response to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917039/applying-granular-right-restriction-in-asp-net-core

Comment: I understand the advantages of your approach now better. However it appears to me like there are several solutions on the market, which you have to buy. This is currently not our approach and I am still interested on how to retrieve the roles of a user from the db for every request...

Comment: There's open source too: AuthZForce, AT&T XACML, WSO2. @cdan

Comment: It'll be cheaper to use the ABAC approach than write your own.

Comment: Well I a gree that the Identity solution of Microsoft might get confusing and limited on a later stage, however right now I think its pretty convenient to just add 1 line to a controller in order to limit its access to one specific role. However I am still not capable of making the link between the identity in asp.net core 2.0 and the database, same goes for the roles...

Comment: Using a framework's solution e.g. Microsoft is great. Look into their claims-based authorization. That'll likely get you what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of discussions and researches in the internet i came to the conclusion to chose pure windows authentication.

It works out of the box and you can already use the active directory groups as roles with [Authorize(Roles = "ADGroupName")] which is really straightforward and nice.