# Map asp.net core 2.0 Identity to existing DB schema

Tags: sql-server, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I have built a small web application with asp.net core 2.0 MVC. In this web application, I did **not** implement any authentication methods so far.

Right now I have an MSSQL database running in the background and I can add/view/edit/delete users from the database. 
I adapted [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-with-asp-net-core-mvc-web-app-using-ado-net/) and followed it pretty closely. However I also added some functionality like localization and stuff, and everything is running pretty smoothly.

My next goal is to enable authentication and authorization. The authentication part shall be straightforward. The goal is that the application will be running as an intranet solution. This means the authentication method just shall check if the Windows User is existing in the previously mentioned database. I don't want to create a separate login. However, it might be that there is a Windows user in the active directory, which is not part of the database. This User should just be able to see a default error page.

I made quite a huge research and I also tried a lot of different stuff, however, I do absolutely not find any "database first" tutorial for this part or any other documentation which explains what to do.

I actually "just" want to teach the asp.net core 2.0 identity framework that it shall look into my user-table and check if the current windows user is existent and if not to forward him to the error page.
A second step would be to load all the roles which this user is assigned to from the mapping table.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: And how will you be updating SQL with windows users???? there is a user.Identity object that would return the windows logged in user, and it is available on application load

Comment: Like I said this part is already written and working. I type in manually the ActiveDirectory username into the user table. I am aware of the User.Identity object - however I still don't know where to write my request if User.Identity.Name exists in my sql user table? I found the IActionFilter class - however I am not sure if this is the right place for this check!?

Comment: on startup.cs you can have a class that returns user from DB and compare with the domain user

Comment: Perfect! Thanks it works. The next step now is to read the roles from the database and write it to the users identity roles... I will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score -2):

Dosc Microsoft has a lot of posts regarding authentication for ASP.NET Core. Here are some of the links to get you started:

[ASP.NET Core Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

[ASP.NET Core Authentication Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)

and a lot more.

Comment: Thanks, I don't need an answer anymore, because I found my solution and described it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50017259/9641435 and here: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1768 - Your answer is however absolutely not specific and does not help with any of the questions raised. So I don't think it will help others with the same problem in the future.

Comment: Well, you might really need those Authorize in your controller